# Harmonic series and monotonicity of $\ln x$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, harmonic-numbers

Prove that ln x is strictly monotone increasing and that $\ln x\to \infty$ as $x\to\infty$ by using the property that the harmonic series diverges.

I don't understand how the harmonic series is relevant here. I know the derivative of $\ln x$ is $1/x$, but I don't know how to get a sum to use the harmonic series...

Comment: After some confusion, I think the question is meant to be:  (i) Show that $\ln x$ is strictly increasing.  (ii) Use part (i) and the divergence of the harmonic series to show that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \ln x = \infty$.  Could you confirm that is correct?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use Riemann sums to get an upper and lower bound for $\int_1^n \frac{dx}{x}$. (You really only need a lower bound, but the upper bound is just as simple...)

Comment: @PeteL.Clark Ummm, $\ln \lfloor x\rfloor < \ln x $ pretty much covers that.

Comment: Well, my answer assumes that $\ln x =\in_1^x\frac{dx}{x}$, so it's easy to see it is non-decreasing, assuming that. Depends on what def of $\ln x$ you are using, I guess, but I'm clearly assuming one definition.

Comment: My interpretation of the question is that we are supposed to show that $\ln x$ is increasing *using the divergence of the harmonic series*.  I agree that it is easy to show in almost any other way.  (It is also easy to show the second part in some other way given that $\ln x$ is increasing, e.g. $\log e^n = n$; done.)

Comment: That's one interpretation. Another is that you are supposed to prove it is increasing, and use harmonic series to show that it diverges. Did you see the word "hint" in my answer? Not sure about you, but I try to avoid giving complete answers to homework-looking questions. I don't always succeed at that...

Comment: Yeah, you just happened to review my four-day-old answer, and not any of the other answers here, just because, you know, nothing personal, and then deliberately took and obtuse view of the question. Nothing about my patient attempt to explain why link-only answers are discouraged here on one of your answers, which, again I did not downvote.

Comment: It's possible to be sincere but still be blinded by an agenda. The reading is obtuse to anybody who thought about the problem, and it was obvious to everybody else who answered the question. You didn't comment on the other answers, did you? Have some self-respect and think a little about your motives.

Comment: For the third time, *thank you for explaining the question* to me.  I left a comment to the question itself and also to your answer, because leaving a comment to someone's answer pings the person and I thought that you might be online to respond right away and because I thought you were the most capable of quickly answering my question...which you did.  (Also, one of the other two extant answers *does not* seem to understand the question, it seems to me, in that it makes no connection to the harmonic series.)

Answer (score 1):

As I commented above, I first found the question very confusing because I read it to mean that we are supposed to use the divergence of the harmonic series to show that $\ln x$ is strictly increasing.  I don't see how to do that.  I also think the question is a bit backwards in some other ways: let me talk through it.

1) What is our definition of $\ln x$?  The one which allows what I think is the intended solution is $\ln x = \int_1^x \frac{dt}{t}$.  Then: if $f(x) = \ln x$, $f'(x) = \frac{1}{x}$, which is positive for all $x > 0$.  It is a standard consequence of the Mean Value Theorem that a function with a positive derivative is strictly increasing.  Or, the other way around, since $\frac{1}{t}$ is continuous and positive, $\int_1^x \frac{dt}{t}$ must be increasing.

2) The manner in which we are supposed to use 1) and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} = \infty$ to show $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \ln x = \infty$ has already been well explained in the answers of Unwisdom and Thomas Andrews.  I have nothing to add there.

3) But still this is a somewhat strange question.  If we know 1) and we are willing to use any properties of the logarithm, we can deduce $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \ln x = \infty$ more easily in other ways.  Namely, since $\ln x$ is strictly increasing, to show that it approaches infinity it is enough to show that it is unbounded above.  If we know that $\ln x$ is the inverse function of $e^x$ then:

$\ln e^n = n$, so $\{ \ln n\}$ is unbounded.

Or if we know that $\ln xy = \ln x + \ln y$, then it follows that 
$\ln x^n = n \ln x$, and so we get $\ln e^n = n$, or even $\ln 2^n = n \ln 2$.  Again, the logarithm function is unbounded.

In fact we can get away with even less: let

$g(x) = \ln(2x) - \ln(x)$.  Then

$g'(x) = \frac{2}{2x} - \frac{1}{x} = 0$,

so (by the Mean Value Theorem) $g(x) = C$ is constant.  Plugging in $x = 1$ we get 
$g(x) = g(1) = \ln 2 - \ln 1 = \ln 2 > 0$ since the logarithm function is strictly increasing.  Then it follows that

$\ln 2^n = \ln (2^n) - \ln(1) = (\ln(2^n) - \ln(2^{n-1})) + \ldots + (\ln(2) - \ln (1)) = n \ln 2$,

and again we get that the logarithm function is unbounded.

4) Now I want to ask: how do we know that the harmonic series diverges?  The most traditional approach is via the Integral Test -- i.e., it goes the opposite way, and we need to use that $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \ln x = \infty$.  So for this not to be circular we need some other method.  There is another such standard method:

> Cauchy's Condensation Test: Let $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ be a real series with 
>   $a_1 \geq a_2 \geq \ldots \geq a_n \geq \ldots \geq 0$.  Then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges if and only if the "condensed series" $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 2^n a_{2^n}$ converges.

Applying the Condensation Test to the harmonic series condenses it to $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 1$, which diverges.  (This special case of the Condensation Test is actually more famous than the Condensation Test and much earlier -- it is due to the medieval mathematician [Nicole Oresme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicole_Oresme) -- but the proof is exactly the same.)

The proof of the Condensation Test is rather short: it is a clever manipulation involving powers of $2$.  My point though is that the argument used in 3) above is also a manipulation involving powers of $2$....a very similar one in fact, which proves a rather special case of the standard properties of logarithm that we use in precalculus and calculus mathematics.  So while it is certainly possible to make the above proof of $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \ln x = \infty$ noncircular, I don't specifically see what is being gained: the geometric argument in question establishes the important asymptotic expansion

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{ \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}}{\ln n} = 1$,

but in my experience one uses this to understand $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}$ in terms of $\ln n$, not the other way around.  For more insight on how to use the Integral Test not just for convergence/divergence but asymptotic analysis of divergent series, see [this blurb of Keith Conrad](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/analysis/sumest.pdf).

Comment: how is knowing $\ln(e^n)=n$, enough to conclude $\ln(n)$ is unbounded?

Comment: @joseph: Since log is increasing we have $\log \lceil e^n \rceil > \log e^n = n$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the function $$f(x)=\frac{1}{\lceil x\rceil}$$ 
where $\lceil \cdot \rceil$ is the *ceiling* function, taking each real number $x$ to the smallest integer $n$ satisfying $n\geq x$.

Observe that for any natural number $k$ we have 
$$\int_{1}^{k}f(x)\, \textrm{d}x=\sum_{j=2}^{k}\frac{1}{j}.$$

It is also evident that for all $x$, we have $f(x)\leq \frac{1}{x}$. Thus:

$$
\int_{1}^{k}\frac{1}{x}\, \textrm{d}x\geq \sum_{j=2}^{k}\frac{1}{j}.$$
You should be able to complete it from here.

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x)=\ln x \rightarrow f'(x)=\dfrac{1}{x}>0 (for \hspace{2mm} x>0)\rightarrow f \hspace{2mm} is \hspace{2mm} increasing.$$
$$\ln x=\int^{x}_{1}\dfrac{1}{t}dt$$
As
$$\min \{ \frac{1}{t}\hspace{2mm}in\hspace{2mm}t\in [i,i+1]\}=\dfrac{1}{i+1}\rightarrow$$
Let $$n=\lfloor x\rfloor \rightarrow \int^{x}_{1}\dfrac{1}{t}dt>\sum^{n}_{i=1}\int^{i+1}_{i}\dfrac{1}{t}dt>\sum^{n}_{i=1}\dfrac{1}{i+1}[(1+i)-i]=\sum^{n}_{i=1}\dfrac{1}{i+1}$$
$$\ln x>\sum^{n}_{i=1}\dfrac{1}{i+1}\rightarrow \lim_{x\to + \infty}(\ln x)\geq \lim _{x\to +\infty}\sum^{n}_{i=1}\dfrac{1}{i+1}=$$
Using $n=\lfloor x\rfloor$
$$=\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum^{n}_{i=1}\dfrac{1}{i+1}=+\infty$$